# googleで'http://'や'https://'を検索する方法

Tags: google-search

googleのurl検索で'http://'や'https://'を検索する方法はありますか?

`inurl:http://`として検索をかけたいのですが。

Answer (score 3):

もし、`http`のサイトだけ検索したの場合には、

```
-"https://"
```

を使えば結構です。

例えばhttpのFacebookを検索すると、こう成ります：
[facebook -"https://"](https://www.google.co.jp/#q=facebook+-%22https:%2F%2F%22)

Comment: 掲載しているリンクだと URL の path に "facebook" が載っているものしか出てこず、 `http://www.facebook.com` が結果に現れないですね。また `-"http://"` でもhttpリンクが検索結果に含まれています。

Comment: googleは、http://www.facebook.com を検索結果として返しません。 [https://www.google.co.jp/#q=site:facebook.com] それよりも http/httpsすら省略されているパターンの事も考える必要がありますね。

Comment: あー。失礼。省略されているパターンはhttpのようですね。　httpsが含まれるのは継続問題ですね。:(

Answer (score 1):

これでどうだろう？

```
allinurl:https://* または allinurl:http://*
```

うーん。ページの後ろのほうになると「allinurlを無視した結果が必要かもしれない」とクエリオプションを無視した結果がでてきますね……。

クエリオプションを無視した結果が出てくるのは、もはやどうすることも出来ないような……。